# react-router not rendering specific routes (React + Redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am using React with Redux. When authenticated i.e. when this.props.isAuthenticated=true the /add is not getting rendered and instead of that / route is rendered. However, if i move /add out of this.props.isAuthenticated condition it is getting rendered. I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import asyncComponent from './hoc/asyncComponent/asyncComponent';
import * as action from './store/actions/index';

const asyncSignUp = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import('./containers/Signup/Signup');
})

const aysncLogin = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import('./containers/Login/Login');
})

const asyncAddStore = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import ('./containers/Add/Add');
})


const asyncGetHome = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import ('./containers/Home/Home');
})

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onTryAutoLogin();
  }

  render(){
    let route = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup" component={asyncSignUp} />
        <Route path="/login" component={aysncLogin} />

        <Redirect to="/"/>
       </Switch>
    );
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated){

        route = (
          <Switch>

            <Route path="/add" component={asyncAddStore} />

            <Route path="/" exact component={asyncGetHome}/>

            <Redirect to="/"/>
          </Switch>
        );


    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">

          {route}

        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
    userData: state.auth.data
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoLogin: () => dispatch(action.authCheckState())
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

authComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const asyncComponent = (importComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            component: null
        };

        componentDidMount(){
            importComponent().then(cmp => {
                this.setState({component: cmp.default});
            });
        }

        render(){
            const C = this.state.component;

            return C ? <C {...this.props}/> : null;
        }
    }
}

export default asyncComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<Route path="/add" component={asyncAddStore} />`, but you declare `const asyncAdd = ...`. I assume `asyncAdd` is supposed to be `asyncAddStore`?

Making that assumption, I think your problem may be outside of the file you provide:

1. **Make sure your `<Switch>` component is inside of a `<Router>`** (or `<BrowserRouter>` component)...you might have one in the parent of your `App.js`
2. **Also make sure you're rendering your App component** (you'll need to wrap your `<Switch>` in a `<Router>` like above) or that you're rendering `<App>`'s parent component, like this...

   ReactDOM.render(
     <React.StrictMode>
       <App />
     </React.StrictMode>,
     document.getElementById('root')
   );

Comment: The props are getting into the class correctly. Also the routes /login and /signup are not visible when authenticated as expected. But /add is not working.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment - hope this helps! If this doesn't work, it would help if you could provide your implementation of `asyncComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already made sure that <Route> is inside <Switch> which is inside <BrowserRouter>. I have added asyncComponent.js. And yes it was asyncAddStore.

Comment: You're also calling `ReactDOM.render()` at the top level, correct?